# Three.js 73 bufferGeometry index & setDynamic

Tags: three.js

With r73  `addAttribute('index'... )` is `setIndex` and I have not any way to get the index attribute and set it dynamic.

`setDynamic( true )`

I create my lines dynamically, first one line with 6 points, next with 14 points, etc. 
My code worked fine with drawcalls & index as attribute. (r71)
Any idea how to do this now ? (r73)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just like you access indices by `getIndex()` you can set them with `setIndex()` with a new `Uint16Array` or modify it by accessing the `.array` property of a [`BufferAttribute`](http://threejs.org/docs/?q=buffer#Reference/Core/BufferAttribute) instance :

```js
// get the BufferAttribute object
var indices = mymesh.geometry.getIndex()

// the actual Uint16Array holding values can now be modified
delete indices.array[0]

// don't forget to flag the BufferAttribute for update
indices.needsUpdate = true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an attribute dynamic when you create it, like so:

```
geometry.addAttribute( 'position', new THREE.BufferAttribute( positions, 3 ).setDynamic( true ) );
```

I assume you can also do this with the index values.

See the full example [here](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_drawcalls).